# configure virtual host to deploy rails application

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost

I am configuring my VPS server i need to have two domain. One is primary domain and other is sub-domain with some references i changed my configuration as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin relic@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName domain.com
        ErrorLog logs/domain.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName admin.domain.com
        ErrorLog logs/domain.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i restart my apache it showing some things like this

```
Starting httpd: [Wed Oct 09 17:55:44 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

And my sub domain too not working

For testing purpose I have pointed both domain to same directory.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to add [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) to your server configuration. Basically to enable name-based virtual hosting.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Hope it helps.